# os.walk() returning some data in lists. os.path.getsize() needs a different data type to work

Tags: python-3.x, list, os.walk, os.path

I've looked at the os docs and tried searching around, but I can't find how to do this.

I'm trying to get os.walk() to bury down into all the folders, subfolders and files of the path i've chosen and print everything above a certain size:

```
for folders, subfolders, files in os.walk("/Users/my_user_name/Downloads"):
    if os.path.getsize(folders) > 2000:
        print(os.path.getsize(folders))
        print(os.path.abspath(folders))
    elif os.path.getsize(subfolders) > 0:
        print(os.path.getsize(subfolders))
        print(os.path.abspath(subfolders))
```

The first if statement will purposelly fail because I want to see the subfolders, but when running

```
        print(subfolders)
```

it returns the information I want, but the data is all in lists:

```
['Hearthstone-Setup.app', 'PokerStarsUK']
['Contents']
['_CodeSignature', 'MacOS', 'Resources']
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

when trying to get the size or absolute path, this isn't possible when the data is returned in this format. Files is exactly the same way; it's only folders that does what I want it to do. I know I've had this problem before, but I can't remember how I got around it.

Can anyone help me to get the data into a different format? Sorry if it's a stupid question, I'm still at the beginner stage and trying to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `os.path.join` on each combination

```
for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk("/Users/my_user_name/Downloads"):
    # Check all subfolders directly in folder
    for subfolder in subfolders:
        print(os.path.join(folder, subfolder))
    # Check all files directly in folder
    for file in files:
        print(os.path.join(folder, file))
```

Or using `glob`

```
import glob
for file in glob.glob("/Users/my_user_name/Downloads/**/*", recursive=True):
    print(file)
```